# Click to expand side editor

Tags: visual-studio-code

I just upgraded to v. 1.25 (deb) and a feature that I liked just doesn't work anymore: on previous version, when I clicked on a side editor that was completely collapsed to the side it would expand into view. Does not work anymore for some reason.

Any settings to restore that behavior?

Comment: Are you talking about side bars? (like "open editors", "workspace", "outline"...)

Comment: When I "Split Editor Right" and push the vertical editor separation line to the far right (editor still partially in view) in the previous version, when I clicked anywhere in that editor I would come back into view. Not anymore.

Comment: OK. I do see that as well with 1.25.

Comment: Problem solved in 1.26.

Comment: _Grid: Automated maximize of minimized editors
One feature we lost during the introduction of the grid editor layout last milestone was the ability to have editors automatically maximize when you focus them and they are in their minimized state. This feature is now working as before_  [Release notes](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_26#_grid-automated-maximize-of-minimized-editors)

Comment: Great! I'll add an answer later on today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented, the [VSCode 1.26 release notes](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_26#_grid-automated-maximize-of-minimized-editors) mentions:

> ### Grid: Automated maximize of minimized editors
>
> One feature we lost during the introduction of the grid editor layout last milestone was the ability to have editors automatically maximize when you focus them and they are in their minimized state.
> This feature is now working as before

[image: https://code.visualstudio.com/assets/updates/1_26/grid-maximize.gif]:

> ### Restore "snap to minimize/maximize" feature with grid editor layout.

This solves [issue 51614](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/51614) (also illustrated [with this duplicate](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/54832)), with [commit 61e0cf0](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/commit/61e0cf066d44a2cb5ca1c38d87c0f190836a2aa1).

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to maximize one of the editors and then be able to expand other editors by focusing on them without manually dragging the separator bar to first maximize one editor first, see the new command as of v1.38:

```
workbench.action.toggleEditorWidths
```

and [How to maximize a split in VScode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53925724/how-to-maximize-a-split-in-vscode/53926099#53926099).  just a little nicer than futzing with dragging the separator bar.