# How can I temporarily maximize an editor group in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I like the split view mode in VS Code but one thing I can't figure out is how to maximize a split view temporarily.

I would like to be able to maximize a split window (as in on one of the windows of a split) for a moment and then restore the layout when I am done with it.

Comment: I have requested this feature here: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/124656 If it gets 20 upvotes they will schedule implementation.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

It looks like **v1.84** will have a new command for toggling the maximization of the current editor group which appears to be exactly what you want:

```
workbench.action.toggleMaximizeEditorGroup

"View: Toggle Maximize Editor Group"
```

Bound by default to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>

See [Commit: Add editor group maximize toggle action](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/commit/5a4c59fa16b7bed5210f448b5c5d7db6e52dbaec). Available in the Insiders Build now.

[image: demo of toggling maximize the focused group]

There is a new command `View: Toggle Maximize Editor Group` (kb(workbench.action.toggleMaximizeEditorGroup)) to maximize an editor group. This will hide all other groups and adds a button to the tab bar, allowing the user to restore the previous layout. When changing the setting `workbench.editor.doubleClickTabToToggleEditorGroupSizes` to maximize, users can double-click on an editor tab to maximize and unmaximize the editor group.

Also note that part of this v1.84 update is the **REMOVAL** of the older commands:

```
View: Maximize Editor Group
View: Unmaximize Editor Group
```

---

**v1.38** has a new command:

```
workbench.action.toggleEditorWidths
```

which can be useful here. It is unbound to a keybinding by default.

Say you bind it like so:

```
{
    "key": "ctrl+alt+b",
    "command": "workbench.action.toggleEditorWidths"
}
```

Then use it **once** to maximize one of the splits - after that switching focus to either one will maximize that one easily.  Basically, using the `workbench.action.toggleEditorWidths` command once will do the work of manually dragging the separator bar for you.

---

**Before v1.38**

From the [July 2018 Release Notes: Automated maximize of minimized editors](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_26#_grid-automated-maximize-of-minimized-editors).

To get this to work you have to **first** **manually** minimize one of the splits (or editors in an editor group).

Drag the separator bar between the editors as far left (or right) as it will go.

Or use the command `View: Maximize Editor Group`.

Then clicking in or otherwise focussing (perhaps with `workbench.action.focusLeftGroup` or similar) the other split will maximize it.

> Note: You can always maximize the active editor via `View: Maximize Editor Group` (workbench.action.minimizeOtherEditors) or reset all editor sizes via `View: Reset Editor Group Sizes` (workbench.action.evenEditorWidths).

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, this seems quite a bit of work around, I mean not exactly what I was looking for but it gets close to what I need. I might accept your solution

Comment: I think it is the best you can do for now.  Maximize one of the editors, then just click in whichever editor you want to maximize (although it'll only go to 90% or so).  In the linked video you can see them dragging the editor separator first.  There are a few issues posted on this but nothing else appears to be in the pipeline besides the above.

Comment: Groan.

(and some more text to fill in StackOverflow's requirement for additional text)

Comment: @Snowcrash See the updated new command mentioned in the answer  I think it does exactly what was wanted.

Answer (score 8):

Or, Just `double click` at `the file name in the split panel's _tab title bar_` 
(the one inside your split panel, not the top most one of your window).

---

- For the ambiguity of maximization:

  - this maximize-*extends* the *split panel* size,
  - not maximize-*fullscreen* the panel.
- If you want "*fullscreen*" (workaround) -- hide the `SideBar`

  - by default hotkey `ctrl+b` & `ctrl+alt+b`
  - or cmd `View: Maximize Editor Group and Hide Side Bars` `workbench.action.maximizeEditor`
  - (just search for the cmd)
- If you want "*fullscreen*" - *zen mode*

  - `ctrl+k z`
  - ref: [Is it possible to make an editor split full-screen in VSCode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52679858/is-it-possible-to-make-an-editor-split-full-screen-in-vscode)

---

- <sub><sup>In some peoples' cases, may not work. But in my case, worked before & works in `Version: 1.83.1 OS: Windows 10 x64`</sup></sub>
- For more info about new version 1.84: [another answer post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77356279/9549068)

Comment: In most IDEs this works, but interestingly vs code doesn't do anything.

Comment: It maximizes the split tab for me.

Comment: @allprog (Base on your upvote, it seems many others have same issue, I dont understand why. ) Did you try **multiple** times? \
If your file tab title is slant - it means its temporary, the **first** double click only makes it persistent. \
Btw, double click on _the middle boundary / the tab title (2nd time)_ splits the panel back into even half.

Comment: @Nor.Z I turned off temp tabs, those were painful for me. No matter where you click on the tab and how many times, nothing happens. I rarely use split editors either, that's not an issue. Ctrl + B hides the navigator but not the terminal. When I double click on the tab, I expect the editor to toggle the full-windowed mode (which vs code apparently doesn't have)

Comment: Yeah, it just moves the separator, like the other "maximize" commands. Version 1.84 changes a number of things to actual maximization, as stated in [starball's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77356279/15261914).

Comment: @allprog updated, seems there was an ambiguity, & you want fullscreen?

Comment: Vscode apparently still does not support the "close all appendices and show only the editor" action. JetBrains IDEs and Eclipse have this with he double click on tab action.

Answer (score 5):

Command + J and Control + B can be used for Mac.

1. View: Toggle Side Bar Visibility
2. View: Toggle Panel

Comment: Ctrl-J and Ctrl-B works for Ubuntu. Nice. I just wish double clicking on the tab handle would accomplish both.

Answer (score 2):

You can double click the tab title/handle of any editor in the editor group to toggle maximization of that editor group (note that if the editor is in preview mode, then double clicking it will first cause it to not be in preview mode (see also [How can I prevent VS Code from replacing a newly opened, unmodified (preview) tab with a subsequently opened one?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38713405/11107541))).

According to [this maintainer comment](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/16927#issuecomment-1776626554), since VS Code 1.84, you can also right click the tab title/handle of any editor in the editor group to toggle maximization of that editor group, and there will be a "Maximize Group" option.

In VS Code 1.84, the behaviour can be changed with the `workbench.editor.doubleClickTabToToggleEditorGroupSizes` setting. Quoting from the defaultSettings.json pseudo file:

> ```json
> // Controls how the editor group is resized when double clicking on a tab. This value is ignored when `workbench.editor.showTabs` is not set to `multiple`.
> //  - maximize: All other editor groups are hidden and the current editor group is maximized to take up the entire editor area.
> //  - expand: The editor group takes as much space as possible by making all other editor groups as small as possible.
> //  - off: No editor group is resized when double clicking on a tab.
> "workbench.editor.doubleClickTabToToggleEditorGroupSizes": "expand",
> ```

The same setting exists pre-VS Code 1.84 since version 1.80 (it was added in [PR #185966](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/185966)), but is a boolean for enabling/disabling expansion and not full maximization, which wasn't added until VS Code 1.84:

> ```json
> // Controls whether to maximize/restore the editor group when double clicking on a tab. This value is ignored when `workbench.editor.showTabs` is disabled.
> "workbench.editor.doubleClickTabToToggleEditorGroupSizes": true,
> ```

In VS Code 1.84, the commands `View: Maximize Editor Group` and `View: Unmaximize Editor Group` can be used in the [command palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette), and are both bound by default to the chord <kbd>ctrl/cmd</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>,<kbd>ctrl/cmd</kbd>+<kbd>m</kbd> (they use the `maximizedEditorGroup` when clause to be context-sensitive). Before VS Code 1.84, the maximization command would cause expansion and not full maximization.

There's also the `View: Toggle Editor Group Sizes` command, which toggles expansion (see the "expand" option of `workbench.editor.doubleClickTabToToggleEditorGroupSizes` instead of full maximization). It's not bound to a keyboard shortcut by default, but you can add a keybinding using its command ID, `workbench.action.toggleEditorWidths`.

There's also the `View: Maximize Editor Group and Hide Side Bars` command, which can be bound with `workbench.action.maximizeEditor`.

Note: you might also want to check out the [Zen Mode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_zen-mode) feature. Also [In VS Code, how can I toggle maximization of the current workbench part / editor group?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58885067/11107541).

Answer (score 0):

Command + B ==> Toggle the Explorer
then
Command + J ==> Maximise the editor tab