# VSCODE : Prevent Double Clicking from Expanding Pane

Tags: visual-studio-code

In vscode when you are working with multiple panes split both horizontally and vertically or a combination of the two, and you double click inside of a pane i.e. the content body it automatically expands. This pushes around all of your panes which sucks to continuously reorganize.

Is there a way to shut this off? I can not find the setting.

Here is a gif of what this looks like http://recordit.co/ClOxfe0CYz

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try resetting the editor sizes with the "`Reset Editor Group Sizes`" from the command palette.  Thereafter, the focused editor will not expand in size.

Maximizing the focused editor only starts to work if one of the editors was previously minimized or maximized.  See [how to maximize an editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53925724/how-to-maximize-a-split-in-vscode/53926099#53926099).

Comment: I have added a gif to this post to demonstrate what happens. Thoughts? Is this what you were referring to?

Comment: Yes, it looks like there are minimized editors.  That will then trigger the "maximize whichever editor I focus" functionality.  The way to prevent that is to reset the editor group sizes.

Answer (score 2):

I found that double click on any tab(when you have any tab split) will `Toggle auto group size` what you experience I believe. So if this happens just double click again on any tab to disable auto resizing.

Comment: that's correct. Double clicking on an editor tab results in this expanding/shrinking behavior. I personally hate it! If only someone could give a clear explanation on how to disable it...There are a couple of days I've been struggling with it and still couldn't find a solution

Comment: Just to add I personally hate this a lot as well - anyone found a fix for this since this comment?

Comment: I greatly dislike it. I ave two widescreen monitors side by side, and and plenty of screen room when displaying two vertical windows. I don't need this feature. It is constantly irritating

Answer (score 1):

After some searching in the settings I was able to resolve this by disabling:
Workbench > Editor: **Centered Layout Auto Resize**

Comment: This doesnt do it, double clicking still expands the pane