# No keybinding command for Atom tab double-click? Maximize and toggle split editor widths

Tags: visual-studio-code

I usually use Atom as my editor, and it has an extension "hey-pane" that allows a keyboard shortcut to expand the active editing tab/pane. I'm trying to do this similar action (gif attached) with vscode. Just adding a keyboard shortcut to this action. Is this an option? Or do I need to take the time to change back to Atom. :(
[GIF DEMO OF ACTION](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RI8lK.gif)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I temporarily maximize an editor group in VS Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53925724/how-can-i-temporarily-maximize-an-editor-group-in-vs-code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This command `workbench.action.minimizeOtherEditors` will maximize the current editor by minimizing all the others.  It does not have a default keybinding but you can set one easily in the Keyboard Shortcuts UI or with this setting in your keybindings.json:

```
{
  "key": "ctrl+tab", // whatever keybinding you wish
  "command": "workbench.action.toggleEditorWidths"
}
```

[You won't be able to use <kbd>tab</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> as the shortcut for various reasons.]

Comment: Thank you so much! Half way there. This does the first initial action but doesn't return the editors to their original state when pressed again, acting as a toggle. Any way to achieve that?

Comment: I edited the answer for different command which toggles between maximized and even editor widths.