# How do I stop VS Code from maximizing the size of an editor group when double-clicking one of its tabs' handles?

Tags: visual-studio-code

When double-clicking a tab, the size of the editor group where it is located becomes larger. Occasionally double-click when my mouse clicks, but I don't want the size of the editor group to change.

- I know that double-clicking again can reset the size of the editor group, but what I need is to restore the size I set, not the default size.
- I couldn't find any relevant settings in the Settings.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I temporarily maximize an editor group in VS Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53925724/how-can-i-temporarily-maximize-an-editor-group-in-vs-code) the info in my answer here is not covered in my new answer there, and I'd rather not have to maintain info in two places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that double clicking a tab invokes the `View: Maximize Editor Group` command, and then double clicking again invokes `View: Reset Editor Group Sizes`. Loosely related issue where I learned about those commands: [Stop auto resizing panes when focused #125997](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/125997).

A PR has been made and merged: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/185966, adding a new setting: `workbench.editor.doubleClickTabToToggleEditorGroupSizes`. The change is released in [VS Code 1.80](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_80). Quoting from the defaultSettings.json pseudo file:

> ```json
> // Controls whether to maximize/restore the editor group when double clicking on a tab. This value is ignored when `workbench.editor.showTabs` is disabled.
> "workbench.editor.doubleClickTabToToggleEditorGroupSizes": true,
> ```

The type of the setting seems to have been [changed in v1.84](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/16927#issuecomment-1776626554). Quoting from the defaultSettings.json pseudo file:

> ```json
> // Controls how the editor group is resized when double clicking on a tab. This value is ignored when `workbench.editor.showTabs` is not set to `multiple`.
> //  - maximize: All other editor groups are hidden and the current editor group is maximized to take up the entire editor area.
> //  - expand: The editor group takes as much space as possible by making all other editor groups as small as possible.
> //  - off: No editor group is resized when double clicking on a tab.
> "workbench.editor.doubleClickTabToToggleEditorGroupSizes": "expand",
> ```

##### Old answer

I tried googling for a way to disable this and didn't find one. Settings for editor tabs are usually prefixed with "`workbench.editor.tab`", and I didn't see a setting to toggle this behaviour. I don't think you can change this via keybindings.json either, since that's for keyboard shortcuts and (as far as I know) nothing to do with the mouse buttons. I'm inclined to think you might be out of luck. <strike>You could try [raising a feature request issue ticket](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&projects=&template=feature_request.md) asking that a setting be added to support disabling this feature. If you do, please comment here with a link to your issue ticket.</strike> The asker has raised a feature-request issue ticket at [Allow to disable editor group maximize on double click #185858](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/185858).