# How to make a terminals tab in the editor view in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is it possible to group terminals into one editor tab in vsocde and have my other tabs open one file?

For example: I can go into the terminals tab and see two terminals in one screen:

[image]

and then I can click on the **info.txt** tab and only see one file opened in the screen:

[image]

Is this possible with VS Code?

Comment: fyi: you can toggle maximization of editor groups: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77356279/11107541

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found one way to do this, but it is out of the scope of vscode.

For Linux users, you can use Tmux for this.

in case you're on windows or mac I'm not sure if tmux is supported, but you can find any alternative shell program which does the same

First install tmux from your package manager, for example on Ubuntu

```bash
$ sudo apt install tmux
```

Then just open a new terminal as usual in vscode, and instead of using the default terminal profile, for example bash or zsh, use tmux. You can do this in vscode, or you can enter the command:

```
$ tmux
```

Directly in the terminal.

Then You can start splitting the terminal the way you like since tmux was originally designed for that.

I'll not cover using tmux you can use YouTube for that, but in general, while inside tmux, press `Ctrl` + `b` and then `Shift` + 5 (to command the "%" character) and a new terminal will be splitted horizontally, if you want vertically then the same thing, `Ctrl` + `b` and then `Ctrl` + `"`.

Then to navigate between the windows, every time you want to move you press `Ctrl` + `b` and then the arrow keys to move between the terminals.

I don't think vscode supports this but anyway this is one way of doing it.

please keep in mind that keyboard shortcuts may vary.

[image]